# Flatten deeply nested JSON vertically convert to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying flatten JSON file but unable to . My JSON has 3 indents repeating sample as below

```
floors": [
        {
            "uuid": "8474",
            "name": "some value",
            "areas": [
                {
                    "uuid": "xyz",
                    "**name**": "qwe",
                    "roomType": "Name1",
                    "templateUuid": "sdklfj",
                    "templateName": "asdf",
                    "templateVersion": "2.7.1",
                    "Required1": [
                        {
                            "**uuid**": "asdf",
                            "description": "asdf3",
                            "categoryName": "asdf",
                            "familyName": "asdf",
                            "productName": "asdf3",
                            "Required2": [
                                {
                                    "**deviceId**": "asdf",
                                    "**deviceUuid**": "asdf-asdf"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
```

I want for area the corresponding values in nested Required1 and for the Required1 **corresponding** required 2.(Highlighted in **)
I have tried JSON normalize as below but failed and other free libs :

### Attempts :

```
from pprint import pprint
with open('Filename.json') as data_file:
    data_item = json.load(data_file)
Raw_Areas=json_normalize(data_item['floors'],'areas',errors='ignore',record_prefix='Area_')
```

### No area value displayed. Only Required 1 Required 2 still nested

```
K=json_normalize(data_item['floors'][0],record_path=['Required1','Required2'],errors='ignore',record_prefix='Try_')
```

---

```
from flatten_json import flatten_json
Flat_J1= pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(data_item)])
```

Looking to get values as below :
Columns expected :
floors.areas.Required1.Required2.deviceUuid
floors.areas.name
(Side by Side)

Please help am I missing anything in my attempt. I am fairly new to JSON loads.

Comment: your initial json has some errors, can you correct it?

Comment: Hi Datanovice,
{
  "floor:": {},
  "val1:": {
    "areas:": {
      "val2:": {}
    }
  },
  "Devices:": {
    "val3:": {}
  }
}

Comment: val1 nested inside val2 nested inside val3 . Need all in a signle row and the next below that instead adding horizontally move down with new values vertically

Comment: can you update with expected output ?

Comment: Table containing columns : name|uuid|deviceId|deviceUuid @user3280146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following JSON (as multiple people pointed out, it's incomplete). So I completed it based on the bracket openings you had.

```
dct = {"floors": [
        {
            "uuid": "8474",
            "name": "some value",
            "areas": [
                {
                    "uuid": "xyz",
                    "name": "qwe",
                    "roomType": "Name1",
                    "templateUuid": "sdklfj",
                    "templateName": "asdf",
                    "templateVersion": "2.7.1",
                    "Required1": [
                        {
                            "uuid": "asdf",
                            "description": "asdf3",
                            "categoryName": "asdf",
                            "familyName": "asdf",
                            "productName": "asdf3",
                            "Required2": [
                                {
                                    "deviceId": "asdf",
                                    "deviceUuid": "asdf-asdf"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
]}
```

You can do the following (requires pandas 0.25.0)

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(
    dct, record_path=['floors','areas', 'Required1'],meta=[['floors', 'areas', 'name']])
df = df.explode('Required2')
df = pd.concat([df, df["Required2"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df = df[['floors.areas.name', 'uuid', 'deviceId', 'deviceUuid']]
```

Which gives,

```
>>>     floors.areas.name   uuid    deviceId    deviceUuid
>>> 0   qwe asdf    asdf    asdf-asdf
```

Comment: Hi @thushv89 , Thank you for your response and sorry for the delay to acknoedge your solution. Unfortunately the solution works well if there is 2 level nesting. Imagine the required 2 tag has more than one entries . Do you have a solution in mind for that ?Below comment has  a sample . Imagine there are many required 2 for a single required 1

Comment: "Required2": [
                                {
                                    "deviceId": "asdf",
                                    "deviceUuid": "asdf-asdf"
                                },{
                                    "deviceId": "bhgk",
                                    "deviceUuid": "bhgk-bhgk"
                                }
                            ]

Comment: @SupreetBose, can you edit your question with the sample and required outputs?